# Is it possible to compute the kubo conductivity of bosons in disorder via mean-field theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bosons, randomness

The kubo conductivity is computed essentially from the current-current correlation function. This works fine when there is no or a periodic potential, as there are a number of ways that can be found in some specialized books. However, when it comes to computing it in a random potential, say in 1D, then the calculations become complicated if one attempts it in a many-body formalism. In a mean-field formalism, it would be possible to integrated over the whole random potential and take a sort of average. My question is, has there been anyone out there who computed the kubo conductivity analytically in disorder and via a mean-field approach?